# How can we avoid integrating changes from one branch to other in perforce?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am new to perforce. I have a requirement to create a trigger to avoid integrating changes from one particular branch say 'branch_testing' to 'main' branch.

How can we do this? Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to absolutely prevent changes from going from branch_testing to main, you need to use the protections table and do one of two things:

1. Remove "read" access to branch_testing.
2. Remove "write" access to main.

Otherwise, even if you implement clever controls on the integrate command, there's nothing to stop a user from doing:

```
p4 sync branch_testing/...
p4 edit main/...
cp -r branch_testing main
p4 submit
```

Comment: Sam, Thanks for your reply. Actually we want to other branches to integrate the changes to main branch. My requirement is, i want to prevent only that particular branch 'branch_testing' changes to integrate to main branch.'' We can achieve this only through trigger i guess?